# Hiding Menu System

Tags: menu

I'm looking for some code on how to create a hiding menu. Basically I'd like to have four links in a horizontal menu. When you click on a link I'd like it to hide the others perhaps above or below to provide a text box. This box would also have information in it that we be inputted by the designer only.

I have a link to preview a template for an example below:
http://www.graphicalwonders.com/archives/brian/Homepage.jpg

Comment: and you've tried... what? We're not here to do your job for you, nor are we here to teach you how to do yours. Show what you've attempted, explain how/why it's not working, and we'll try to help fix it.

Comment: This is called an "accordion menu". You should be able to find some resources with that.

Comment: @Jeremy Roberts Please accept an answer to your question should there be one.

Answer (score 0):

[jQuery UI](http://jqueryui.com/accordion/) - 
[Accordion API](http://api.jqueryui.com/accordion/) - 
[Viral Patel](http://viralpatel.net/blogs/create-accordion-menu-jquery/)

Check out these links for examples of Accordion menus. I find the Viral one to be easier to use, however the jQuery UI & API explain more in detail how it works.